# Show that the set $B = {T: F ^ {n} \rightarrow F ^{m} | p = 1, .., m, q = 1, ..., n} $. is basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ a field and $V$ the vector space of all transformations $ T^{pq}: F ^{n}\rightarrow F ^{m} $.

Show that the set $B$ is a basis of $V$; here $B = {T: F ^ {n} \rightarrow F ^{m} | p = 1, .., m, q = 1, ..., n} $ where, for $\alpha = (x_ {1}, ..., x_ {n}) $, the k-th component of $T ^ {pq} \alpha$ is given by $(T ^ {pq} \alpha) _ {k} = \delta_ {pk} x_ {q}$.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited your definition of the $k$th component of $T^{pq}\alpha$; before it didn't depend on $k$.

Comment: @GregMartin  Thanks for you help Greg Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a basis for a vector space is a linearly independent set that spans the vector space. So you have two things to prove about $B$.

Is $B$ linearly independent? Suppose you have a linear combination $T = \sum_{p,q} c_{pq} T^{pq}$ that equals the zero vector in $V$. (Do you know what the zero vector in this particular $V$ is?) You need to prove that each $c_{pq}$ equals $0$. What happens if you apply $T$ to $(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$?

Does $B$ span $V$? Can you write down, by hand, a way of writing any $T\in V$ in the form $T = \sum_{p,q} c_{pq} T^{pq}$? (Again, what happens if you apply $T$ to $(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$?)

I suspect that the obstacle to solving this problem is not an insufficient understanding of a basis, but rather an insufficient understanding of this vector space $V$. That might help you concentrate your efforts.